# How to easily store different types of values in a single class/structure while also being able to retrieve said values in c++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to build a basic language interpreter in C++, for fun and to learn something new. I need a way to store the tokens I get from lexical analysis. These should also store the token's value, if it has one, for example, if it is an int, string or a float literal. I also need to easily get the value I am storing in the token out, in as little code as possible.

First I just stored the text of each token and let the interpreter do the converting to int or float when it needed. I realized this is very inefficient, especially if I'm gonna have hundreds of thousands of string conversions(for example, in a loop). Then I tried the current approach, which involves having a base class and three other classes that inherit from it, like so:

```
class Token {
public:
    Type m_type;
    std::string m_text;

    Token(const std::string& text, const Type& type) : m_text(text), m_type(type) {} 

    virtual void getValue(int&) = 0;
    virtual void getValue(double&) = 0;
    virtual void getValue(std::string&) = 0;
    virtual ~Token() {}
};

class IntToken : public Token {
public:
    int m_data;

    IntToken(const std::string& text, const Type& type, const int& data) : 
        Token(text, type), m_data(data);

    void getValue(int& val) {
       val = m_data;
    } 
    void getValue(double& val) {}
    void getValue(std::string& val) {}
};
```

The rest of the classes are the same as IntToken, just hold different data types. In this way i can hold all tokens like this:

```
std::vector<Token*> tokens;
```

The problem is, I now have to check each time I want to extract some data from a token, which type of data that is. And that involves a lot of switches in my code. So in other words, I have an elegant way to store my tokens, but a very unpractical way to retrieve their value, if I need to.

So my question is, is there a better way to what I want to achieve?

Comment: Look into _de-/serialization techniques_

Comment: You can always use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the [Kaleidoscope](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/index.html) for inspiration.  Kaleidoscope is a "my first language" for LLVM, as a tutorial.

Comment: The *visitor pattern* could help.

Comment: You are trying to reinvent `std::variant`, perhaps just try using it. BTW an interpreter shouldn't be re-examining tokens each time it executes a piece of code. It should build an efficient internal representation of the code instead.